# What piece of classical music is quoted in Bela Fleck and the Flecktones' "Sinister Minister"?

Tags: classical-music

This is from Victor Wooten concert, he and band "Bela Fleck" performs their song Sinister Minister.

I believe this part, that's starts from 3:26, heavily inherits from classical music.

And I do like to know what classical music is this.

[link to video on youtube](https://youtu.be/q0Q4CBDFaEc?t=3m26s)

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question (hence a comment) I was pleasantly surprised to find that Shazam does seem to support classical music at long last (but no doubt will still not work with live music)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds to be based on [Bach's Preludium in C Major](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXMVkQ70I88), perhaps best known as the accompaniment to [Charles Gounod's Ave Maria](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyBU2DbfSx0).

Comment: Interestingly enough at the time that this recording was released I was a music journalist and a personal friend of Bela Fleck and Victor Wooten, in Nashville, Tennessee. I was not aware of any "classical connection" to this piece. Thanks for this very interesting observation.

Comment: @WheatWilliams, do you have any interviews recorded? Text, audio, video, whatever.

Comment: I used to have the printed article I wrote about Victor Wooten on my website. I'll see about putting it back up. Unfortunately I did not keep the audio interviews (recorded onto analog cassette tape).